# graphql-codegen not running with config file

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen

In my `package.json` file I've got script entry that runs `graphql-codegen` but it complains that the `--config` argument is invalid:

```
$> yarn gen
yarn run v1.21.1
$ graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml
Error: Unknown argument: config
...
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Since I believe the default file name is `codegen.yml` anyway, I try to run it with out that argument and nothing gets generated:

```
$> yarn graphql-codegen
yarn run v1.21.1
$ /home/aaron/projects/my_app/node_modules/.bin/graphql-codegen
Done in 0.17s.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure exactly what I did to fix this. I believe that I had also installed `graphql-codegen` globally and tried to uninstall it with `sudo npm uninstall graphql-codegen` which removed a bunch of packages but the executable still exists:

```
$>which graphql-codegen
/usr/bin/graphql-codegen
```

However I decided to run `yarn graphql-codegen init` on a whim to see if `init` was valid and because I couldn't remember if I hadn't tried that already. I got the set up questions like normal so I `ctrl+C`'ed and just ran `yarn graphql-codegen` and it worked! Then I ran `yarn graphql-codegen --watch` to test that it took options and that also worked.

If anyone gets this issue, I hope these tips help you.

Answer (score 19):

for me this solved the issue

Yarn

```
yarn add -D @graphql-codegen/cli
```

npm

```
npm i -D @graphql-codegen/cli
```

[installation guide doc](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 5):

Try it: `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`

**rm** http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rm.1.html

> *remove files or directories*
> **-f, --force** *ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt*
> **-r, -R, --recursive** *remove directories and their contents recursively*

**node_modules** https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/folders

> You can think of the node_modules folder like a cache
> for the external modules that your project depends upon. When you npm
> install them, they are downloaded from the web and copied into the
> node_modules folder and nodejs is trained to look for them there when
> you import them (without a specific path).

**npm install** https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install/

> This command installs a package and any packages that it depends on.
> If the package has a package-lock, or an npm shrinkwrap file, or a
> yarn lock file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by
> that, respecting the following order of precedence:
>
> - npm-shrinkwrap.json
> - package-lock.json
> - yarn.lock

Answer (score 4):

Might also be that you have [apollo's graphql-codegen package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-codegen) installed, which also exposes a binary called `graphql-codegen`, which accepts args `schema` and `output`, but not `config`.

Comment: Well its apollo's code gen that I am using but the exact packages I have installed are: `@graphql-codegen/cli`, `@graphql-codegen/introspection`, `@graphql-codegen/typescript`, `@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations`, `@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo`.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to install @graphql-codegen/cli.

Answer (score 0):

graphql.config.yml

```
schema: http://localhost:8081/graphql
extensions:
  codegen:
    generates:
      ./schema.graphql:
        - schema-ast
```

package.json

```
{
   "codegen": "graphql codegen --config graphql.config.yml"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by using `graphql-code-generator` instead:

```
"scripts": {
    "graphql:generate": "graphql-code-generator"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i removed the space before the file name, so:
`codegen.ts` instead of  `codegen.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the lib:

```
yarn remove graphql-codegen
rm -rf node_modules
```

codegen.ts file

```
import { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  schema: "http://localhost:8081/graphql",
  documents: ["src/**/*.tsx"],
  generates: {
    "./src/__generated__/": {
      preset: "client",
      presetConfig: {
        gqlTagName: "gql",
      },
    },
  },
  ignoreNoDocuments: true,
};

export default config;
```